# create button, add event, and adding some animation

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-animation, android-button

I'm trying to create something similiar to the image below:

[image: Pic]

when I click button 1:

- the square 2 show font "h" and blue background,
- the square 3 show font "e" and blue background,
- the square 4 show font "l" and blue background,
- the square 5 show font "l" and blue background,
- the square 6 show font "o" and blue background,

the font and background in square no 2,3,4,5,6 appears sequentially.

and when I click square 2, then:

- the square 3 show font "E" and red background,
- the square 4 show font "L" and red background,
- the square 5 show font "L" and red background,
- the square 6 show font "O" and red background,

the font and background in square no 3,4,5,6 appears sequentially.

and same thing happened when I click another square.example when i click square 3, then:

- the square 2 show font "H" and red background,
- the square 4 show font "l" and blue background,
- the square 5 show font "l" and blue background,
- the square 6 show font "o" and blue background,

the font and background in square no 2,4,5,6 appears sequentially.

Is there a way that I can do this within an Android app without using opengl?

edit:

by sequentially I mean in order and adding some delay (like 1sec) per square

the font "h,e,l,l,o" and "H,E,L,L,O" are stored in Array.

Comment: Regarding the font and background change for a single button, they should just appear with the new values?

Comment: @Luksprog yes the values are stored in arrays.

Comment: You can easily make that using a `Handler` to post the text and background updates at the target time intervals.

Comment: @Luksprog ok thank you for the info. I'm going to research it. could you give me the example if you dont mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment you can do that with a `Handler` posting the appropriate `Runnable` object at the desired time.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // the handler
String[] text = { "h", "e", "l", "l", "o" }; // the text
TextView[] views = new TextView[5]; // the views 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

> when I click button 1:

The code you can use:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        int counter = 0; // needed so we know where we are in the arrays

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // when this Runnable is done we set the background
                    // color, the text, update the counter(to update the
                    // next TextView) and repost the same variable
                    views[counter].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    views[counter].setText(text[counter]);
                    views[counter].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    counter++;
                    if (counter < views.length) {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // keep it in the
                                                            // arrays bounds
                    } else {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(this); // we finished
                                                        // iterating over
                                                        // the arrays so
                                                        // reset stuff and
                                                        // remove the
                                                        // Runnable
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }

            }, 1000); // 1 second delay!
        }
    });
```

> and when I click square 2, then:

This is basically the same thing as above, you just need to make sure you don't update the view that triggered the change:

```
// set as the tag for the 2,3,4,5,6 views their position in the array
for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
    views[i].setTag(i);
    views[i].setOnClickListener(mListener);
//...
```

You can use that tag and a counter to update only the proper views:

```
OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

        int counter = 0;// needed so we know where we are in the arrays

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int whichOne = (Integer) v.getTag(); // gett he views
                                                        // position in the
                                                        // arrays
            // check if we clicked 2
            if (counter == whichOne) {
                counter++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // on every iteration check to see if we aren't trying
                    // to update the view that was actually clicked
                    // if it's the view that was clicked then increment the
                    // counter
                    if (counter == whichOne) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    views[counter].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    views[counter].setText(text[counter]);
                    views[counter].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    counter++;
                    if (counter < views.length) {
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    } else {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    };
```